# How to add multiple checkbox in array and add the value on condition base - react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-paper

I am implementing checkbox in my aplication , Here invoiceResponse is a aaray it has two object. I am maoing it and displaying in below ui code . Now I have to add checkbox in it with condition.
Like it will display 2 card value one has 10.00 and second has 20.00 and below I jave one customText " Total amount"
So if i click on first card which has 1 value so in totak amount it should display 10 and if i click both then it should display 30.
Please help
[image: similar like this UX]
[image]

// array api response

```js
invoiceResponse: [
  {
    remainingAmount: {
      unit: "GHS",
      value: "10.00",
    },
    id: "FINV-101010632629-22",
  },
  {
    remainingAmount: {
      unit: "GHS",
      value: "20.00",
    },
    id: "FINV-101010632345-33",
  },
];
```

//  UI Code

```js
const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);

{formValues.activeTab === "By Invoice" &&
  invoiceResponse.map((data, index) => {
    return (
      <View key={index}>
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "white",
            borderRadius: 10,
            height: hp("10%"),
            marginTop: hp("1%"),
          }}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "white",
              padding: hp("2%"),
              borderRadius: 10,
              flexDirection: "row",
              justifyContent: "space-between",
            }}
          >
            <View>
              <CustomText
                text={data.id}
                textStyle={[
                  styles.textH3,
                  { color: themeObj.buttonTextColor },
                ]}
              />
              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <CustomText
                  text={"Remaining Amount: "}
                  textStyle={[styles.btnTxtMed, { color: "#777777" }]}
                />
                <CustomText
                  text={parseFloat(data.remainingAmount.value).toFixed(2)}
                  textStyle={[
                    styles.btnTxtMed,
                    { color: themeObj.buttonTextColor },
                  ]}
                />
              </View>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <CustomText
                  text={"Due date: "}
                  textStyle={[styles.btnTxtMed, { color: "#777777" }]}
                />
                <CustomText
                  text={formatDate(data.paymentDueDate)}
                  textStyle={[
                    styles.btnTxtMed,
                    { color: themeObj.buttonTextColor },
                  ]}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
            <View>
              <Checkbox
                status={checked ? "checked" : "unchecked"}
                onPress={() => {
                  setChecked(!checked);
                }}
                color={"#FC0"}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
          <CustomText
            text={`Total amoutn ${"value"}`}
            textStyle={[
              styles.btnTxtMed,
              { color: themeObj.buttonTextColor },
            ]}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  })}
```

Comment: Where is your checked state? Please add the code / logic for that to your question.

Comment: @RubenSmn directly I am calling setChecked ,I have just updated my question . I am confused , how to add dynamic checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you only have **1** state for multiple checkboxes. Instead what you could do is keep track of the `ids` of which data item have been checked.

Here we create a array to keep track of the checked ids. The function helps us toggle the ids from the state.

```js
const [checkedIds, setCheckedIds] = useState([]);

function toggleChecked(idToToggle) {
  setCheckedIds((prev) => {
    if (prev.includes(idToToggle)) {
      return prev.filter((id) => id !== idToToggle);
    }
    return [...prev, idToToggle];
  });
}
```

When the rendering, in the `Checkbox` we check if the `id` is in the array and add our toggle function.

```js
function Component() {
  const [checkedIds, setCheckedIds] = useState([]);

  function toggleChecked(idToToggle) {
    setCheckedIds((prev) => {
      if (prev.includes(idToToggle)) {
        return prev.filter((id) => id !== idToToggle);
      }
      return [...prev, idToToggle];
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {formValues.activeTab === "By Invoice" &&
        invoiceResponse.map((data, index) => {
          return (
            <View key={index}>
              <View
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: "white",
                  borderRadius: 10,
                  height: hp("10%"),
                  marginTop: hp("1%"),
                }}
              >
                <View
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: "white",
                    padding: hp("2%"),
                    borderRadius: 10,
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    justifyContent: "space-between",
                  }}
                >
                  ...
                  <View>
                    <Checkbox
                      status={
                        checkedIds.includes(data.id) ? "checked" : "unchecked"
                      }
                      onPress={() => {
                        toggleChecked(data.id);
                      }}
                      color={"#FC0"}
                    />
                  </View>
                </View>
                ...
              </View>
            </View>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can get the total value by using the `checkedIds`.

```js
const total = invoiceResponse.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (checkedIds.includes(curr.id)) return acc + curr.remainingAmount.value;
  return acc;
});
```